# Android - Reading a file using scanner, how to get to the file

Tags: java, android, file, dir

Hello i got a quite annoying problem
i'd like to read text files similar to this

```
KEY
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
KEYEND
```

i tried to use scanner class, because it can return results as strings, decimals, whatever

```
   public static void LoadStuff(String Name) {
      Scanner reader = null;
      try {
         reader = new Scanner(new File(Name));
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.d("damn", "FAIL");
      }
         if(reader != null)
            Load(reader);
   }


private static void Load(Scanner reader) {
      while (reader.hasNext()) {
         String result = reader.next();
         if (result == "KEY") {   // may be  result.equalsignorecase
            while (result != "KEYEND") {
               int index = reader.nextInt();
               Log.d("Index", String.valueOf(index));
            }
         }
      }
            reader.close();
   }
```

i cant do above, cause scanner cant find the file, parsing like "file.txt" doesnt work, tried also with path
like this "res/data/file.txt" also doesnt work
where should i put the file and how to get the directory to make it work
thanks

Answer (score 5):

This code uses `getAssets()` method of your class.  You need to put the text file in the assets folder of your Android project.  The `getAssets` method returns a AssetManager object.  The `open(String.format("filename.txt"))` method returns a InputStream.  The InputStream is the parameter for DataInputStream.  Then you use that as the input to the Scanner.

```
try {
    DataInputStream textFileStream = new DataInputStream(getAssets().open(String.format("filename.txt")));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(textFileStream);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String aLine = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(aLine);
    }
        sc.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code that I have always used to access files inside my current project (also text files) is:

```
textFileStream = new DataInputStream(getAssets().open(String.format("myFile.txt")));
```

You can always fill in the String.format portion with your own filled string.

The key has always been the

```
getAssets()
```

part.

So in your case, you may have something that looks as follows:

```
reader = new Scanner(new File(getAssets().open(String.format("myFile.txt")))); 

OR

reader = new Scanner(new File(getAssets().open(Name)));
```

The File constructor can take in a InputStream, the getAssets().open will return an InputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Put your text file in the `assets` folder, then read it using `getAssets().open("file.txt")`.

[Example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/ReadAsset.html)

Comment: If you could accept the answer that would be great. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 0):

1. Try giving path like this `"/sdcard/file.txt"`
2. And please always you "`equals`" when comparing objects. `Never use "==" or "!=" with Objects. (String is an object too in Java)`

   eg:

   ```
    if (result.equals("KEY"))` {       // equals is used
       `while (!(result.equals("KEYEND")))` {  // !equals is used

          int index = reader.nextInt();
          Log.d("Index", String.valueOf(index));
       }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To write a file to internal storage use `openFileOutput`. According to Android [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) doc:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

To use Scanner to read the file:

```
File f = new File( getFilesDir(), FILENAME );
Scanner s = new Scanner( f );
```

Note: [getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29) returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.

To see what you output to your file then check out: [is it possible to see application data from adb shell the same way I see it mounting SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017073/is-it-possible-to-see-application-data-from-adb-shell-the-same-way-i-see-it-moun).

Other [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
File data = new File("yourfile"); 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(data);
int i = 0;
while(sc.hasNextLine){
    String Lines = sc.nextLine;
    System.out.println(Lines);
    i++;
}
```