# Can't open Android device monitor, always showing error

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-device-monitor

I have to run Android device monitor but when i open android device monitor shows a warning:

[image: this is the warning shows when I open ADM]

If I select the option "yes" then shows another error:

[image: this is the error message when I select "yes" option]

I have tried to reinstall JDK, Android studio but it seems no changes. also, i tried to run monitor as administrator using terminal but got the same error log. I am using MacBook, android studio version 3.0.1 and I have installed Java 9.0.1. please help me to run my android device monitor to show my SQLite database or any other way to check it.

Comment: in the meantime you can use ADB to pull data then just sqlite database browser software such as http://sqliteman.yarpen.cz/  to view and manipulate data inside you db.

Comment: how to pull data using ADB?

Comment: you can refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598152/how-do-i-pull-the-sqlite-database-from-the-android-device

Comment: I think the problem is Java 9.0.1, the ADM works when I uninstall Java 9.0.1 and install java 1.8.0_162. I don't know the actual problem is.