# Android eclipse DDMS - Can't access data/data/ on phone

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

After lot of searching i found below result but did't work for me. i did through the same procedure but unable to open data/data folder in eclipse ddms it shows su not found every time.

I want to open data/data folder of device so that i can view the flies which i store in internal storage.please suggest the alternative of this. can i open it with any tool ?

On rooted device you can do this:

Open cmd prompt

Type 'adb shell'

su

Press 'Allow' on device

chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.application.pacakage /data/data/com.application.pacakage/*

Go to the DDMS view in Eclipse
After this you should be able to browse the files on the device.

Comment: I think you should copy the directory from internal storage to external storage programmaticaly. Then you can retrieve the same external storage from ddms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see all files you are storing inside your app folder, Run the adb with your app permissions, The you can see all your app folders.

```
adb shell
run-as com.your.package
cd data/data/com.your.package
ls
```

Then navigate through all your files

for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/16461386/4804264