# Android 6.0 permission denied

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, permission-denied

I am using Android 6.0. I have an application that copies executable file (compiled for arm) to the app data folder. 
In the app I have set the executable permissions to:

```
chmod 777 /data/data/pckname/files/executable
```

when I try to run the file using adb shell I get this message

```
/system/bin/sh: /data/data/pckname/files/executable: can't
execute: Permission denied
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I tried

```
ls -l
```

and this is the result

```
-rwxrwxrwx u0_a54   u0_a54    1620988 2016-12-14 13:59 execFile
```

is the problem in the user?

Comment: are you using virtual device or a real one ?

Comment: @quicklearner A real device.

Comment: @Doha My guess the device has to be rooted, otherwise you will not get access

Comment: Please read this post. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017073/is-it-possible-to-see-application-data-from-adb-shell-the-same-way-i-see-it-moun) might help you

Comment: [please read this post once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017073/is-it-possible-to-see-application-data-from-adb-shell-the-same-way-i-see-it-moun) it might help you