# Can a user edit SharedPreferences of the apps they are using on their phones

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I want to ask if any android user can edit the SharedPreference of an app they are using.

I have a key in the SharedPreference of my app named email, i want to ask if the user can change it outside the app.

Comment: root user can do anything bro (or sister!)

Comment: here you can find the answer....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017073/is-it-possible-to-see-application-data-from-adb-shell-the-same-way-i-see-it-moun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to ask if the user can change it outside the app.

**On a non-rooted phone:** No

**On a rooted phone:** Yes